# Is there a way to get the index of a widget in a List

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi im trying to get the index of a particular widget in a list

```
static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
     Index(),
     Achievements(),
];
```

so get it when to get a certain widget

`_widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex)`

but I am having a hard time getting the index of a widget.

I tried  `int index = _widgetOptions.indexOf(Index());` but it is returning a value of -1 which translate to not found.

Comment: Please share what you tried. For instance, did you try the `indexOf` method?

Comment: I think you can follow this link 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexOf.html

Comment: tried indexOf and returns -1;

Comment: When you call '_widgetOptions.indexOf(Index())' to find Widget index, I think that two 'Index()' Widget instance is made. So I think that 'Index()' instance is different between '_widgetOptions' and 'Index()'.

Answer (score 1):

When you call '_widgetOptions.indexOf(Index())' to find Widget index,
the two 'Index()' Widget instance will be made.

So the 'Index()' instance is different between '_widgetOptions' and 'Index()'.

Below is example code and result.
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // the text entered by the user
  Widget? indexWidget;
  Widget? achievements;
  
  
   Widget Index() {
    return Container();
  }
  
   Widget Achievements() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(),
      ]
    );
  }
  
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    indexWidget = Index();
    achievements = Achievements();
    
    List<Widget?> _widgetOptions = <Widget?> [
       Index(),
       Achievements(),
    ];
    
    List<Widget?> _widgetOptions2 = <Widget?> [
       indexWidget,
       achievements,
    ];
    
    print(_widgetOptions.indexOf(Index()));
    
    print(_widgetOptions2.indexOf(indexWidget));
    print(_widgetOptions2.indexOf(Index()));
  }
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of widgets are in your list but it would be better to use you list in `ListView.builder` and if the widgets are wrapped in something like `gestureDetector` or `button` just create an int variable `index = - 1` and when one widget is clicked or pressed use a `setSate(() => index = i)` . (I call `i` the index in your `ListView.builder`.

Comment: a Stateless Widgets

Answer (score 0):

So let's talk about `List<T>` in Dart!

If you look at the source code for `indexOf` you'll see this documentation:

```dart
  /// The first index of [element] in this list.
  ///
  /// Searches the list from index [start] to the end of the list.
  /// The first time an object `o` is encountered so that `o == element`,
  /// the index of `o` is returned.
```

Pay special attention to the `o == element` meaning that the item that you're trying to find has to implement the `==` operator. If you look deeper into the source code for Flutter you will see that `StatelessWidget` implements `DiagnosticableTree` and that itself implements the `==` operator:

```dart
  /// Compare two widgets for equality.
  ///
  /// When a widget is rebuilt with another that compares equal according
  /// to `operator ==`, it is assumed that the update is redundant and the
  /// work to update that branch of the tree is skipped.
```

You can prove that it all works by writing this code:

```dart
final widget1 = const MyText();
final widget2 = const MyText();
final List<dynamic> texts = [widget1, widget2];
final i1 = texts.indexOf(widget1);
final i2 = texts.indexOf(widget2);
assert(i1 == 0);
assert(i2 == 1);
```

And you'll see that Flutter is indeed able to find those elements at the right index. So that's the first point.

However, after more than 2 years of Flutter development I've never had to do this which tells me what you're doing can be achieved in many other ways, such as using a `ListView.builder()` that creates a widget for all the `itemCount` that you provide to it.